# Open a new ViewController on Button Click if text entered matches Parse string

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uibutton, viewcontroller

So I'm trying to create a registration page with availability by Zip Code. For instance, a user can only register if the service is available in their area (zip code).

So far I have a Text field for Zip Code and a button labeled "Check Availability".

I have a Parse Backend and I tested a connection to it using their setup guide and it works.

How can I go about checking the text that was inputted to see if it matches a zip code in my parse database? So if a the zip code the user entered matches one in the parse database I need a new ViewController called "Register" to open and the user can begin their singup/registration.

Current Code:

```
class checkAvailability: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var zipCode: UITextField!
@IBAction func checkAvailBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("beginSignUp", sender: self)
}

func checkZip() {
    var usersZipCode = zipCode.text
    var queryZip = PFQuery(className: "zipCode")
    queryZip.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.
            println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) zip codes.")
            // Do something with the found objects
            if let zipCodes = objects as? [PFObject] {
                if zipCodes.contains({ $0["zipCodes"] == usersZipCode) {
                print("your in!") // transition to the new screen
                }
                else {
                print("your out.") // do whatever
                }
                }
            } else {
                // Log details of the failure
                println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
            }
        }

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Code
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a PFQuery to pull down the list of zip codes into the app, then simply check to see if the string the user entered is in the list.

-- EDIT --

```
    let query = PFQuery(className:"ZipCode")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.
            print("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) zip codes.")
            // Do something with the found objects
            if let zipCodes = objects as? [PFObject] {
                if zipCodes.contains({ $0["zip_code"] as! String == usersZipCode }) {
                    print("your in!") // transition to the new screen
                }
                else {
                    print("your out.") // do whatever
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide some code I can use as reference?

Comment: Generally, it works best here if you include the code you are having trouble with in your question and we can help you make it work. That said, I posted something in my answer, maybe it will help.

Comment: What happened when you ran the app and entered a bad zip code? Did it do what you wanted it to?

Comment: The app was not able to build properly

Comment: It throws a lot of wrong syntax errors with that code. Check out my updated code.

Comment: I suggest you look up the documentation for `performSegueWithIdentifier` and then read the comments I put in the code. Hopefully, a light bulb will go off over your head.

Comment: I've got the idea behind performSegueWithIdentifier and I have it working correctly. The thing is I get a lot of errors using the code your provided, the errors are syntax and have to do with the brackets. I just can't figure out how to resolve it.

Comment: I found and fixed an error in the `zipCodes.contains` line. Warning, the above is written in Swift 2.0. If you are using 1.0, you will have to change the prints to printlns. *That said* there are some huge issues with the code in your question that have nothing to do with my code. If you continue having problems with it, I think you should start a new question with your code and what the compiler is complaining about.